# RMI server´s jar runs good on Red Hat but doesn´t work on windows

Tags: windows, maven, jar, rmi, policy

i have a RMI server builded with Maven  and onejar-maven-plugin, this server runs good on eclipse STS and the jar on  Red Hat too, but if i try to run the jar on my cmd on windows, the server RMI throws me the next exception:

> java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source),
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source),
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source),
>   java.lang.Thread.setContextClassLoader(Unknown Source),
>   com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader.loadClass(JarClassLoader.java:629),
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source),
>   modeloconfigurador.cache.manager.rmi.InterfazRMICategoriaImpl.startRMIServer(InterfazRMICategoriaImpl.java:65),
>   modeloconfigurador.cache.manager.rmi.InterfazRMICategoriaImpl.setPuertoRMI(InterfazRMICategoriaImpl.java:92),
>   modeloconfigurador.cache.manager.impl.ServicioCacheImpl.inicializa(ServicioCacheImpl.java:168),
>   serviciocache.CachePrincipal$1.run(CachePrincipal.java:79),
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source),
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method),
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source), java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source),
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)]

it  seems that the java.policy on java JDK doesn´t have permissions, but  it does have.

i run the jar on E: and i open the cmd like administrator

here my code:

RMI Server:

```
private void startRMIServer() {
    try{

        log.trace("Consultando privilegios java.security.policy");
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy","java.policy");

        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

        log.trace(new StringBuilder("Creando Registrry en el puerto ").append(puertoRMI));
        _registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(puertoRMI);

        _interfazRMICategoriaMC=(InterfazRMICategoria)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this,puertoRMI);
        String nombreObjR="ObtenerCategorias";

        _registry.bind(nombreObjR, _interfazRMICategoriaMC);
        log.info(new StringBuilder("(RMI) Objeto Remoto colocado en Registry con el nombre ").append(nombreObjR));

    }catch(Exception e){

        log.error(new StringBuilder("podible error por permisos del security manager: ").append(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace())));

    }
}
```

this is the java.policy file form the JAVA_HOME:

```
// Standard extensions get all permissions by default

grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

// default permissions granted to all domains

grant {
        // Allows any thread to stop itself using the java.lang.Thread.stop()
        // method that takes no argument.
        // Note that this permission is granted by default only to remain
        // backwards compatible.
        // It is strongly recommended that you either remove this permission
        // from this policy file or further restrict it to code sources
        // that you specify, because Thread.stop() is potentially unsafe.
        // See the API specification of java.lang.Thread.stop() for more
        // information.
        permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "stopThread";

        // allows anyone to listen on dynamic ports
        permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:0", "listen";

        // permission for standard RMI registry port
        permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1099", "listen";

        // "standard" properies that can be read by anyone

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor.url", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.class.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.name", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.arch", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.separator", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "path.separator", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "line.separator", "read";

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.name", "read";

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.name", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.name", "read";
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

the project has its own java.policy file, but for eclise is invisible

The issue is when i try to run the JAR only on windos, in the IDE eclipse STS  on windows runs good and when i run the same  JAR on Red Hat runs good too (modifying the file java.policy from JDK in use).

Answer (score 0):

> this is the java.policy file form the JAVA_HOME

But you aren't using the java.polcy file from JAVA_HOME. You're using whatever one is in the current directory, if any.

Run your application with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure` and you will see exactly what permissions are being sough and granted, and what policy files if any are in effect. **Clearly** it isn't the one in your post.

Comment: in fact you are right, when i run the maven project with netbeans IDE the project uses the java.policy in the current directory, but when i use the same project on eclipse STS, the java policy in use is from the JDK, anyway the project has its own java.policy file, but for eclise is invisible and again the issue is when i try to run the JAR only on windos, in the IDE eclipse STS  on windows runs good and when i run the same  JAR on Red Hat runs good too (modifying the file java.policy from JDK in use).

Comment: I'm not going to waste my time trying to understand that uncapitalised unpuncuated mess, but the problem is as I described. How it runs under Eclipse is really of no interest. The issue is how it runs standalone.